# 2-application Symfony 1.4 ROUTING

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I do have two application, e.g. "frontend" and "b2b". Frontend is my main application for users. b2b is then of course for business-customers. When I am going to type

www.myhomepage.com -> My routing goes to something like  frontend/module/start/index.php

When I am going to type:

www.myhomepage.com/b2b.php/ -> My routing goes to something like b2b/module/b2bstart/index.php

How can I set the routing that when I type

www.myhomepage.com/b2b that I got to b2b/module/b2bstart/index.php???

TIA!

Craphunter

PS: Using symofony 1.4

Answer (score 0):

A way could be to use a rule inside the file *.htaccess*:

```
RewriteRule ^b2b myproject/web/b2b.php [NC,L]
```

I used this type of rule, positioned after `RewriteEngine On`, in the file *.htaccess* outside to my project folder